# t-statistic vs two-sample t-tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

When and in which context is the [t-statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-statistic) used?

$ t = \frac{\hat{\beta} - \beta_0}{se(\hat{\beta})} $

where $\beta_0$ is a non-random, known constant, which defines the null-hypothesis in the form $H_0: \beta = \beta_0 $; and $se(\hat\beta)$ is the standard error of the $\beta$

I used to think that the above formulation should only be used to assess whether a parameter in a statistical model is statistically significant, but I have increasingly seen it used in other contexts. For example, assessing whether the results of an [a/b test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) are statistically significant. Unfortunately I can not link to the documents where I have seen this use, but in a nutshell, I have seen this methodology being used:

1. Take the daily sales of version a and b
2. calculate the difference of the average of daily sales for the a and b variant (the time series don't necessarily have the same length)
3. calculate the std deviation of the difference of the averages: $\sigma_{a-b}$
4. apply the above where $\hat{\beta}$  is set equal to the difference in averages and $se(\hat\beta)$ is replaced by $\sigma_{a-b}$

Using the above methodology:

- yes, we can build a linear model $y = a$ for the difference in average daily sales where $a$ is just the intercept
- yes, working with averages allows to use the [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) to infer convergence to normality

...but I suspect something is lost along the way..

Is there a loophole in the methodology described above?
What about the sample size and the tests for the [difference in mean that apply to two samples](http://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/difference-in-means.aspx)?

Comment: are you asking what other test statistics are t-distributed?  Or are you asking us to infer things about your notation here?

Comment: @Taylor, I see your point. I made the q much more specific.

Comment: I edited to add a tag and make the title more specific but now you've adapted the Q you might want to change the title to match it more closely.